# AWS Application load Balancer : Create Target group with IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a question using AWS Application Load Balancers.

I have a domain in A account, and an instance in B account.
I want to make a load balancer in A account to target an instance in B account using IP address.
I trying to create a target group using IP address, but  I can't move forward.

Can I have any solution or vision about this problem?

Comment: "trying to create a target group" what exactly are you using? What IP address, public, private? Your question lacks details and is sadly unclear.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? It would make more sense to have both the Load Balancer and the target in the same AWS Account and VPC.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it would make more sense to put the Load Balancer and the target resource in the same AWS Account and same VPC.

If this is not possible, you could consider using [VPC Peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html), which connects two VPCs together. This way, the Load Balancer can direct the traffic to a **private IP address** in the other VPC, without going via the Internet.

Or, you could use [VPC Sharing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html), which allows multiple AWS Accounts to use the *same* VPC.